# How to remove captcha verification from Firebase phone auth using flutter web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, flutter-web

I wants to remove or a make invisible google recaptcha verfication.
My code for verifying mobile number and sign in

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: "+91${customMobileController.text.toString()}",
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

For sign in

```
var authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
    verificationId: verificationId,
    smsCode: otp,
);

await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithCredential(authCredential)
    .then((value) {})
    .catchError((error) {});
```

Comment: @YauhenSampir actually brother i go through that question and it's in javascript and i wants it in flutter web

Comment: What is the difference? Do you think that Flutter Firebase API different than Javascript?

Comment: It is impossible to achieve what you want on any Firebase SDK, Flutter it or not. 
Firebase uses reCAPTCHA to prevent abuse, such as by ensuring that the phone number verification request comes from one of your app's allowed domains.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth

Comment: @YauhenSampir Library for both is different. In flutter there is no utility for handle google recaptcha like javascript. So i wants to know how to achieve it using dart

Comment: @YauhenSampir Ok it is impossilbe but how can we invisible it like google recaptcha v3 in dart code

Answer (score 16):

You can remove reCaptcha by Enabling the Android Device Verification API in Your Project on google cloud console. You can do that by Adding Your Project there.

After that you should also add SHA-256 key in Your Firebase Project in Project Setting.

Now there will be no reCaptchaa to verify to that your are not a robot.

Comment: Thank you. Hope it will work for Mobile Phone too.

Comment: What about ios?

Comment: How can we enable this for iOS platform?

Comment: Is there any way to implement this for IOS?

Comment: Adding a link to Youtube simple example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opBwTxicw1k

Comment: Did anyone figure it out how to do it for iOS?

Comment: In iOS, Firebase will verify by way of sending silent push notifications to the device - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

Comment: Did not find *Android Device Verification API* in google cloud console maybe they rename that and I already SHA-256 key but still seeing reCaptchaa screen in android any idea how to fix?

Comment: @Nicks exactly same +1